# Using CSS #attached doesnt load stylesheet in

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am using Drupal's `hook_form_alter` to add a stylesheet into one of my forms (user registration form).  My code does add the stylesheet to `jquery.extend(Drupal.settings)` as `sites\/all\/themes\/mytheme\/css\/font-awesome-min.css:1`, but this does not allow me to use the stylesheet as when I reference classes that are in it, they don't load as the CSS file does not show up as an import URL or link in `<head>`.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ( $form_id == 'user_register_form' )
    {
    $form['#attached']['css'] = array(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/css/font-awesome-min.css');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add 'file' at the end of $form['#attached']['css'] array, like this:

```
$form['#attached']['css'] = array(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/css/font-awesome-min.css', 'file');
```

Comment: Thank you, except this doesnt seem to change anything in the source apart from in jQuery.extend to sites\/all\/themes\/mytheme\/css\/font-awesome-min.css":1,"file":1  - No file shows in <head>.  Any ideas?